# How does Svelte reactivity work inside functions?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have some serious problems with reactivity in Svelte. I have isolated what I think is at least one of my main issues. When bind:ing a variable to a checkbox, the reactivity seems to break when setting the variable inside a function, but not outside. Is this intended behavior? In that case why? And what is the intended work flow?

Example code, a Svelte component:

```html
<script>
    let foo = true;

    // This assignment works both on the plain text view (Foo: true/false)
    // and on the checkbox
    // setInterval(() => foo = !foo, 500)

    // This assignment works only on the plain text view (Foo: true/false)
    // but not for the checkbox
    function action() {
        foo = !foo;
    }
</script>

Foo: { foo }<br />
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={ foo } on:click|preventDefault={ action } />
```

Svelte REPL to see this problem in action: https://svelte.dev/repl/73de7d705ab3442786710cd88ea3f625?version=3.12.1

Answer (score 3):

If you wrap your variable declaration in a `setTimeout` without any time limit (making it default to 0 and therefore run as soon as possible) your code will work.

```
function action() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        foo = !foo;
    });
}
```

I wish I could explain why this works, but I can't...

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is much simpler, because the two-way binding by itself does everything you need. So, this does it:

```
<script>
  let foo = true;
</script>

Foo: { foo }<br />
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={ foo } />
```

I know the question is two years old, but I think it needed better closure.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your problem is cause by the `bind:` option. Having this will cause the *foo* to be updated twice: once for the 'action' and once behind the scenes when the binding kicks in.

Just removing the `bind:` should work

```
<script>
    let foo = true;

    // This assignment works both on the plain text view (Foo: true/false)
    // and on the checkbox
    // setInterval(() => foo = !foo, 500)

    // This assignment works only on the plain text view (Foo: true/false)
    // but not for the checkbox
    function action() {
        setTimeout(() => foo = !foo, 1000);
    }
</script>

Foo: { foo }<br />
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" checked={ foo } on:click|preventDefault={ action } />
```

This make sense because you do **not** want to have two-way-binding for the checked state to foo. You only want the checkbox to *reflect* the value of foo.

Comment: The code example works, but the trick is the setTimeout(). It works even if I add bind: back, as long as the foo-declaration is inside that timeout and not directly inside the function first scope.

Comment: @Lilleman: The setTimeout() is hiding the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

This binding issue isn't with Svelte's reactivity, it's using `preventDefault` on the click event. The HTML `checked` attribute never changes, [because the checked attribute doesn't fire any JS events to update the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked).

In Svelte, you don't need to set `foo` since it's already bound to the HTML state.

```
...
function action() {
        console.log(foo)
    }
</script>

Foo: { foo }<br />
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={ foo } on:change={ action } />
```

But if you don't want HTML to change before something else, declaring `action` as async works fine with `on|click|preventDefault`:

```
async function action() {
        let data = await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
        foo = !foo
        console.log("changed!")
        return data
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to cancel the event with the usage of preventDefault, because it would stop the default behaviour of the checkbox.

And therefore the `reactivity` is `broken`. If you wrap the reassignment of foo in a setTimeout you just tricking the event loop and the default is not prevented.

So if you like to stop the propagation of the event use preventDefault with the suggestion from [Filip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57971355/5341567).

```
    <script>
        let foo = true;

        // This assignment works both on the plain text view (Foo: true/false)
        // and on the checkbox
        // setInterval(() => foo = !foo, 500)

        // This assignment works only on the plain text view (Foo: true/false)
        // but not for the checkbox
        async function action(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                setTimeout(() => {foo =! foo});

        }
    </script>

    Foo: { foo }<br />
    Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={ foo } on:click={ action } />
```

Comment: preventDefault is needed because for example the state should not change before an async operation is done in the function. So sadly it does not solve my issue, but thank you. :)

Comment: I adpated the answer to your suggestion. So that the state changes are handled in the async action and the default is prevented

Comment: Hm, I tried moving preventDefault in a REPL but can not get that to work either? https://svelte.dev/repl/f6fefe4f1656429d980d964c1ff25b53?version=3.12.1

(The difference is that I added e to action: so the preventDefault() actually runs)